# Dynamically detect signature algorithms in JCE

Tags: java, digital-signature, jce

My application is on Java 7. I want to digitally verify a signed message sent by a calling system.

My problem is, I don't know the signature algorithm that has been used in the calling system.

In the runtime in JCE, how can I detect the signature algorithm to verify?

All the examples I have seen have the algorithm is pre-known or hardcoded

https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-digital-signatures-example/
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/index.html

I am using Sun provided JCE implementation and cannot use any third party providers like Bouncy Castle.

I can do ASN parsing to detect the OID of the algorithm but again AFAIK JCE does not have any ways to detect the algorithm by passing the OID in java 7.

Please check here for that [Fetching MessageDigest by OID is failing in Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48315041/fetching-messagedigest-by-oid-is-failing-in-java-7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extract the algorithm OID from signed message, but this is generally not the right way to solve your issue, because you have to deal with all the possibilities and the code will be too complex

- Padding algorithm: PSS, PKCS#1, etc
- Key algorithm: RSA, EC, DSA
- Hashing algorithm: SHA1, SHA256, etc.

In the usual signature formats: `XMLDsig`, `CMS`, `PAdES`, `JWS` the signature algorithm is included in the signature container as an attribute

See this XMLDsig example using DSA with SHA1
[image: xmldsig]

So, **I suggest to include the signature algorithm in the message sent by calling system**. For example in JWS signature is included a header like this `{"alg":"RS256"}`

---

Of course if you are working with a limited set of keys and algorithms (i.e RSA-PKCS#1 with SHA) you could extract the OID from the signature decrypting the message and parsing the ASN.1

Comment: thanks a lot for your inputs...i was able to get the OID from the message but MessageDigest.getInstance() was failing in Java 7 if i pass OID...is it possible in Java 7 anyway to dynamically get the algo name from OID ?

Comment: No, you would need a map with a conversion table or use Bouncycastle that has an algorithm finder

Comment: yes i wanted to avoid maintain this mapper in my code :(..unfortunately i cannot use bouncy castle due to some restrictions

Comment: Bouncycastle finder is basically a map. See source code of  [DefaultAlgorithmNameFinder](https://www.javatips.net/api/bc-java-master/pkix/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/operator/DefaultAlgorithmNameFinder.java) The code is simple and the number of algorithms are limited. I suggest to copy the code to your project

Comment: i will do so...thanks a lot pedrofb...your inputs have been very useful